# Equality test in `if` command returning the error message "no such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm writing a shell script and I'm doing

```
if ["$item0" == "$item1"]
then
echo match
fi
```

but it's giving the error message "No such file or directory" on the line when run. The items above do contain file paths if that helps.

Comment: please elaborate what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to note the spaces for between variables and the brackets, they matter. Also if `then` is on the same line as `if`, you need a `;`

Corrected syntax:

```
if [ "$item0" == "$item1" ]; then
    echo match
fi
```

P.S. if `match` is supposed to be a variable, make sure it's `echo "$match"`

Comment: The same line thing was just my formatting which I think I've fixed. The spaces around the brackets was the problem, I owe you a beer.

Comment: For those who come after, this is because `[` is a program named `[`. Sh requires spaces around program names, and that causes this issue.

Answer (score 3):

To begin, when posting here you should probably always give the full error messages, possibly removing any sensitive data.

Let's begin by explaining how your line is wrong, first:

1. In bash, `[` is basically a synonym for `test`, with a few minor differences (the most noticeable one is that it expects its last argument to be `]`). Run `man test` for more info. `test` takes in stuff with its own syntax, then returns a proper value depending on whether its input evaluated to true or false. So, since `test` is a program, and not a bash build-in, it must take it's inputs as separate parameters (note the spaces):

   `[ "$item0" = "$item1" ]`

   The `=` instead of the `==` is a stylistic preference. They do the same thing, but `=` is preferred by some people since bash is not C.
2. Second, bash needs to know when the input to an external command ends. This is done with `;`. To make this clearer, suppose I do this

   `if true then echo foo fi fi`

   Now I'm trying to print out `foo fi` if the if statement evaluates to true. See my problem? Bash doesn't know when to terminate the input to your echo command.

Properly rewritten:

```
if [ "$item0" = "$item1" ]; then echo match; fi
```

Comment: `=` instead of `==` is more than a stylistic preference: the former is POSIX, not the latter, so that some shells might not interpret it correctly (e.g. `dash` which comes always handy for such pedantic remarks ;-). Of course, if you know that your script will always be interpreted by `bash`, then both are indeed equivalent.

Comment: `test` has been a bash builtin for quite some time.

Comment: Woops, I should have said `test` is both a program, and a bash builtin with very similar syntax and behaviour. Thanks for the correction, Virgile.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, if you're using bash, `[[` is a lot easier to use and more reliable than `[` (unless you really need portability, `[[` has for some time been the preferred bash idiom). For one thing, it's not necessary to quote parameter expansions with `[[`, and you also don't have to worry about empty strings. It also features both pattern matching (with `==`) and regex matching (with `=~`).

Comment: `[` is required by posix.  It cannot be deprecated if `bash` is to be a compliant shell.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: posix itself deprecates features, like `echo`, which are required by posix. But posix only reserves `[[`, so its use is not portable. So it's fair enough that "deprecated" might have been too strong.